# How to create an alias for conda activate and rename shelltab in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I tried to create an alias for conda acitvate in Powershell but didn't get any luck so far. On my profile.ps1

1. First I tried:

> ```
> function Get-CondaActivate { & conda activate}
> New-Alias -Name ca -Value Get-CondaActivate -Force -Option AllScope
> ```

It does nothing when `ca myenv`. So I supposed I need argument, then

> ```
> function Get-CondaActivate { & conda activate $args}
> New-Alias -Name ca -Value Get-CondaActivate -Force -Option AllScope
> ```

I got error msg:

> Enter-CondaEnvironment : Cannot process argument transformation on
>   parameter 'Name'. Cannot convert value to type System.String.

So how can I create an alias of `ca myenv` to replace `conda activate myenv`?

I would also like to have an alias to rename the powershellISE tab:

$psise.PowerShellTabs[1].DisplayName = 'new_name'

I think 1 and new_name needs to be replace by an argument. But totally no idea how to do it. :(

Thanks!

J

Comment: change `$args` to `$args[0]` or `"$args"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a typed parameter in a function you need to declare it!

```
function Get-CondaActivate {
  param([string]$EnvName)
  & conda activate $EnvName
}
```

Otherwise make sure you pass only the argument you need, or convert the `$args` array to a string before passing it to `conda`:

```
& conda activate $args[0]
# or
& conda activate "$args"
```